# Show Document Thumbnail of images - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, sharepoint-rest-api, thumbnail

I can currently display thumbnail of documents using rest api by using the ServerRedirectedEmbedUri-

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?select=id,Title,EncodedAbsUrl,EncodedAbsThumbnailUrl,EncodedAbsWebImgUrl,FileLeafRef
```

But i also have images e.g png files stored in the library.
But for the images files the rest api returns null for ServerRedirectedEmbedUri

Any ideas how i can get the thumbnail for images e.g png .

I can use **getpreview.ashx**

But would like to use the same query for both. Is it possible?

Comment: What's the column name of the image column?ServerRedirectedEmbedUri?

Comment: Thanks Amos. But not sure what you mean? The image was uploaded just as the documents were uploaded

Comment: I mistakenly thought you were using the new column type Image in SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 2):

You may have a try below methods:

- getpreview.ashx. This is recommended as i find that Delve uses this solution to get thumbnails

`https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/s01/_layouts/15/getpreview.ashx?path=https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/s01/Shared Documents/4215097.png`

- SP.Publishing.EmbedService/EmbedData

`https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/s01/_api/SP.Publishing.EmbedService/EmbedData?url='https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/s01/Shared Documents/4215097.png'&version=1`

- MS Graph API or SharePoint Rest API V2

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-thumbnails?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/sharepoint-rest-graph

Answer (score 0):

I tried getting thumbnail URL using CSOM but same should be possible with REST APIs as well.

Referring: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73167962/form-thumbnail-url-for-sharepoint-large-video-files

I found a way to generate the thumbnail URL using drive API. There are properties on File object VroomDriveID and VroomItemID. Using these properties we can format the link as below:

> https://{tenantname}.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.1/drives/${VroomDriveID}/items/${VroomItemID}/thumbnails/0/c400x99999/content?preferNoRedirect=true

I got thumbnail URL by using below code:

```
let thumbnailURL = "";
let uniqueID = "{file's unique id}";
let resolution = "c400x99999";
let caml: ICamlQuery = {
ViewXml:
<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='UniqueId' /><Value Type='Text'>${uniqueID}</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>
};
// get list items
const fileItems: IItems = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("DocLibTitle").getItemsByCAMLQuery(caml, 'FieldValuesAsText, File/VroomDriveID,File/VroomItemID');
console.log("Items: ", fileItems);
let VroomDriveID = fileItems[0]["File"]["VroomDriveID"];
let VroomItemID = fileItems[0]["File"]["VroomItemID"];
thumbnailURL = "https://{tenantname}.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.1/drives/${VroomDriveID}/items/${VroomItemID}/thumbnails/0/${resolution}/content?preferNoRedirect=true";
console.log(thumbnailURL);
```